# How to access controller from one window in another window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I have a WPF application with two xaml windows, one named `MainWindow.xaml`and other is `addNewsWindow.xaml`.

In `MainWindow.xaml` I have a `DocumentViewer` and a button named `Add News` that takes me to the other window named `AddNewsWindow.xaml`.

This is my `DocumentViewer` control in `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<DocumentViewer x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="docViwer" 
   Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
   BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" 
   Margin="1,2,40,1">
```

[image]

On my `addNewsWindow.xaml` I have lots of controls to take user input and a button to browse and select word file, which to be displayed in the `DocumentViewer` in the `MainWindow.xaml`:

[image]

**The problem:**

When coding the click event for the Add button in the `addNewsWindow.xaml` (which when pressed should take the word file convert it to XPS and put in the Document viewer in `MainWindow`), I can't reference to the `MainWindow DocumentViewer` and put the converted XPS file into the `DocumentViewer`.

AddNewsWindow.cs

```
private void FilePathBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create OpenFileDialog 
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

    // Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".doc";
    dlg.Filter = "Word documents|*.doc;*.docx";

    // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox 
    if (result == true)
    {
        // Open document 
        string filename = dlg.FileName;
        filePathTBox.Text = filename;
    }

}
private XpsDocument ConvertWordToXps(string wordFilename, string xpsFilename)
{
    // Create a WordApplication and host word document 
    Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    try
    {
        wordApp.Documents.Open(wordFilename);

        // To Invisible the word document 
        wordApp.Application.Visible = false;

        // Minimize the opened word document 
        wordApp.WindowState = WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;

        Document doc = wordApp.ActiveDocument;

        doc.SaveAs(xpsFilename, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXPS);

        XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(xpsFilename, FileAccess.Read);
        return xpsDocument;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error occurs, The error message is  " + ex.ToString());
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        wordApp.Documents.Close();
        ((_Application)wordApp).Quit(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
    }
}

private void AddNewsBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string wordDocument = filePathTBox.Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(wordDocument) || !File.Exists(wordDocument))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The file is invalid. Please select an existing file again.");
    }
    else
    {
        string convertedXpsDoc = string.Concat(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "\\", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ".xps");
        XpsDocument xpsDocument = ConvertWordToXps(wordDocument, convertedXpsDoc);
        if (xpsDocument == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // MainWindow.docViewer = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
       docViewer.Document = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> The name docViewer does not exist in the current context

I don't know how to reference the `DocumentViewer` in `MainWindow` from the `AddnewsWindow.cs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how you're creating and showing the `AddNewsWindow`. It may be possible for you to pass the `MainWindow` to the `AddNewsWindow` (via `this`):

```
var addNewsWindow = new AddNewsWindow(this);
```

The `MainWindow` could define a method to update the document:

```
public void SetDocument(XpsDocument xpsDocument)
{
    docViewer.Document = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
}
```

Then, from `AddNewsWindow`, you can call:

```
mainWindow.SetDocument(xpsDocument);
```

Alternatively, instead of passing the `MainWindow` to the `AddNewsWindow`, you may be able to obtain the `MainWindow` directly:

```
var mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

The reason you need to cast it is that `Application.Current.MainWindow` returns an instance of `Window`, not your `MainWindow`. You'll need `MainWindow` in order to call its `SetDocument` method.